# How to disable line wrapping in LaTeX layer?

Tags: spacemacs, wrapping

The [LaTeX Layer](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/latex/README.html) by default wraps a line after column 85 by inserting a new line while typing and moving the current word to the new line. When the line is a comment, it even automatically inserts the comment prefix.

How can one disable this behaviour?

The emacs variables `word-wrap` and `truncate-lines` seem to have nothing to do with this, they only change how text is displayed while the above behaviour actually inserts new lines.

Comment: It's probably using `auto-fill-mode`. You can add a hook to `latex-mode` to disable it, or maybe there's some other way to configure that in spacemacs.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Thanks, this seems to be the mode I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As largely seen on the web, adding off-switch for the `auto-fill` minor mode to the `(La)TeX` major mode [won't work anymore](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12926), not even with `'append`. As [duianto states](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/12926#issuecomment-565794827), the solution has been properly documented in [the `auto-fill` section of the `LaTeX` layer (in development)](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/develop/layers/+lang/latex#auto-fill).

Change LaTeX's layer line

```
latex
```

to

```
(latex :variables latex-enable-auto-fill nil)
```

Comment: this is the one that works now

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2022-07: This does not work anymore.** See other answers for a working solution.

The automatic wrapping is done by the minor mode `auto-fill-mode` (as [hinted](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42285/how-to-disable-line-wrapping-in-latex-layer/42312#comment66452_42285) by [DoMiNeLa10](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/12563/dominela10)).

To disable it, add this to function `dotspacemacs/user-config` in `.spacemacs`:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'spacemacs/toggle-auto-fill-mode-off)
```

There is also the `latex/auto-fill-mode`, but that doesn't seem to be a mode itself (doc: "Toggle auto-fill-mode using the custom auto-fill function.").

See the [layer documentation for auto-fill](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/latex/README.html#auto-fill) for fine-grained (latex specific) control of where auto-fill should be enabled.

Comment: While this worked at first, recently auto-fill-mode would be active again when loading latex mode, with the same settings. Now it works again (emacs 26.1, spacemacs 0.200.13 (didn't change), packages updated ~28.08.18).

Comment: Not working on spacemacs dev by the way.

Comment: this doesn't work any more; the other answer here works